# unable to run simulator directly using the xcode

Tags: ios

i have problem in running my ios application directly on the simulator it will take to many times to run application and still not running and in xcode the status bar it will display only this message "attaching and my application name like textscroll like attaching textscroll" and it will still process and simulator will open but only show the black screen. It will tack 2 hours to much time just simple hello world application please give me solution if any one have the solution thank you in advanced.

But i will try one solution that run the application and then stop the application after that open simulator and run my application on the simulator so that will run but problem in this way is i will not debug my application using this way so please give me solution .

Comment: Go to the command line (Terminal.app) and tell me if you see `127.0.0.1` appear when you run `grep localhost /etc/hosts`.

Comment: i will try but that will not display the 127.0.0.1 terminal take to much time

Comment: What do you mean "terminal take to much time"?  It should take seconds.

Comment: i will enter the command grep localhost /etc/hosts and then enter but it should not give me 127.0.0.1 not even anything so thats way i am write it take to much time

Comment: OK, so you don't get 127.0.0.1 appearing.  That is the root-cause of your issue, I believe.

Comment: thnx but how to solve this problem any idea so please tell me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is a well-known issue where `localhost` is not mapped to `127.0.0.1` (the IPv4 loopback address) which prevents the debugger from attaching to targets.

You will need to correct `/etc/hosts`:

- Start Terminal.app
- Become root:

  ```
      $ sudo bash
  ```
- Edit `/etc/hosts` using `vi` (easiest when root):

  ```
      # vi /etc/hosts
  ```

This is what my `/etc/hosts` file looks like:

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
fe80::1%lo0     localhost
```

Comment: i will try but it look like this please check it will right or not

Comment: Wishtree-Macs-Mac-mini:~ Krunal$ sudo bash
sudo: /private/etc/sudoers is mode 0644, should be 0440
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
Wishtree-Macs-Mac-mini:~ Krunal$ vi /etc/hosts






















192.168.1.102 Wish009-pc
192.168.1.104 Wish003-pc
192.168.0.113 Abhishek-PC
192.168.1.120 JG
192.168.1.104 DS005-PC                                                                                                         
"/etc/hosts" 5L, 116C

Comment: @alfa OK you need to run "fix permissions" (or whatever it's called) from `Disk Utility` first.

Comment: how to run fix permissions please tell me

Comment: how to fix problem please give me the solution

Comment: @alfa You do it with `Disk Utility`.

Comment: sorry to say this question again again but i am new in mac user so i don't know actually how to solve the this type of utility problem so please help me what to do to solve this problem please @trojanfoe please

Comment: i will try to repair disk permission with the disk utilities option on mac but it will still face same problem to run my application on stimulator so please tell me the solution if any one have please thnx in advance.

Comment: @alfa In that case my answer is not correct and you should not accept it as the answer.  I have no further advice to give you.

Comment: k k thnx @trojanfoe for your advise and if you have the solution in future so please give me \